# Java filling in an array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, int

How would one go about filling in an array so that, for example, if you had the following array.

```
int[] arr = new int[5];
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 3;
arr[2] = 7;
arr[3] = 2;
arr[4] = -4;
```

so it would look like

```
arr = {1, 3, 7, 2, -4};
```

and you would pass it into your method to get a result of

```
arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4};
```

so that you essentially are filling in the numeric gaps.  I'd like to make this under the assumption that I don't know how long the array passed in is going to be to make it a more universal method.

my current method looks like such right now...

```
public static void fillArray(int[] numbers){
    int length = numbers.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i ++){
        if(numbers[i] <= numbers[i + 1]){
            length += numbers[i + 1] - numbers[i];
        }else if(numbers[i + 1] < numbers[i]){
            length += numbers[i + 1] - numbers[i];
        }

    }
}
```

I have length to determine the size of my new array.  I think it should work but I'm always down for some input and advice.

Comment: You need to post your attempt. Asking how to only is not sufficient.

Comment: I'm essentially trying to create a fillArray method that would fill in the numeric gaps of the first array to get the second one.

Comment: @user3529923 Ahh. Okay. So what have you tried? Where are you stuck? What restrictions (if any) are you under for implementation?

Comment: I put up what I have thus far as far as determining how long my new array should be.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like homework, providing algorithm only:

- Navigate through the elements of the current array.
- Get the distance (absolute difference) between the elements in the array.
- Summarize the distances.
- Create a new array whose length would be the sum of the distances.
- Fill the new array using the elements of the first array and *filling the gaps*.
- Return the array.

Answer (score 1):

Like Luiggi Mendoza said, looks like HW, so here's another algorithm:

- insert the first element into a list of integers.
- loop on the rest of the elements.
- for each two array elements X[i-1], X[i], insert the missing integers to the list
- after the loop - use [guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html) to turn the List to array.

Comment: Yes, but it returns Interger[] and not int[].

Comment: Hmmm, that would be problematic.

Answer (score -2):

This works. just check for array size < 2 for safety.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {1, 3, 7, 2, -4};

    Integer[] result = fillArray(arr);

    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(result[i]);
    }
}

private static Integer[] fillArray(int[] arr) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

    list.add(arr[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int prevItem = arr[i-1];
        int gap = arr[i] - prevItem;
        if(gap > 0){
            fillGap(list, prevItem, gap, 1);
        } else if(gap < 0){
            fillGap(list, prevItem, gap, -1);
        }
    }

    return list.toArray(new Integer[0]);

}

private static void fillGap(List<Integer> list, int start, int gap, int delta) {
    int next = start+delta;
    for (int j = 0; j < Math.abs(gap); j++) {
        list.add(next);
        next = next+delta;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ArrayGap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1, 3, 7, 2, -4};
        int high, low;
        List<Integer> out = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length - 1;  i++){
            high = arr[i];
            if(arr[i] < arr[i+1]){
                for(int j=arr[i]; j<arr[i+1]; j++){
                    out.add(j);
                }
            } else {
                for(int j=arr[i]; j>=arr[i+1]; j--){
                    out.add(j);
                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println(out);
    }

}
```